# #1062 - Duplicate entry '%-test-' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm trying to use a MySQl backup .sql file through phpMy Admin in MAMP, but getting this error:

```
SQL query: 

--
-- Dumping data for table `db`
--
INSERT INTO  `db` (  `Host` ,  `Db` ,  `User` ,  `Select_priv` ,  `Insert_priv` ,       `Update_priv` ,  `Delete_priv` ,  `Create_priv` ,  `Drop_priv` ,  `Grant_priv` ,  `References_priv` ,  `Index_priv` ,  `Alter_priv` , `Create_tmp_table_priv` ,  `Lock_tables_priv` ,  `Create_view_priv` ,  `Show_view_priv` ,  `Create_routine_priv` ,  `Alter_routine_priv` ,  `Execute_priv` ,  `Event_priv` ,  `Trigger_priv` ) 
VALUES 
   (  '%',  'test',  '',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',          
      'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'N',  'Y',  'Y'), 
   (  '%',  'test\\_%',  '',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',       'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'N',  'Y',  'Y'), 
   (  'localhost',  'phpmyadmin',  'phpmyadmin',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',      
      'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y'  );

MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '%-test-' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

And it's saying the error is in this line here:

```
  '%',  'test',  '',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',      'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'Y',  'N',  'N',  'Y',  'Y'
```

Any hints?  Any way I can ignore this error through MAMP as I found here: http://linuxadminzone.com/ignore-mysql-error-while-executing-bulk-statements/ ??

EDIT:

Here is the db output (I think):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`),
  KEY `User` (`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database privileges';
```

Comment: Does the table already have rows in it? If you're getting dupes on a PK, I suspect it does...

Comment: Sorry Michael, I'm a complete noob at this, could you explain?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the table? I suspect you have 'Host' as PK, which you're trying to add twice.

Comment: @user1751660 Post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE db;`  The column `Db` appears to be a primary key, but you are inserting duplicate values into it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It looks you're trying to dump and load your mysql db, which is probably not what you really want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get my site going locally, so I have backed up the sql file because the site comes up with a "Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL" error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to insert two lines with a empty user `''`. After the first line with an empty user is inserted, attempting to insert another will result in a key violation.

Comment: So I should delete the first line after "VALUES" in the first example?

Comment: That may help to avoid the duplicate key issue.